# Inserting or Adding previously removed PivotItem throws invalid argument exception but works, why?

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
if (!Pivot.Items.Contains(PrevRemovedPivotItem))
{

   //Pivot.Items.Insert(1, PrevRemovedPivotItem);
     Pivot.Items.Add(PrevRemovedPivotItem);
}
```

> Both the ways throw same exception but at the same time adds the pivotitem.

What's wrong?

Comment: There must be something else because I'm unable to reproduce the issue. You should create a new project with just a Pivot, then add all the logic back until the exception is raised again.

Comment: yes you are right. But in my project it always throw an exception at the insert line.

Comment: Sure. But unfortunately, unless you give enough code to reproduce the issue, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: No Clue what else is related to that particular line of code as I have debugged it very carefully. So can't post more code.
Just patched it with a little tweak of try-catch block. :)

Comment: Let's dig a bit more, for science! Are you modifying some properties of the pivot items at some point after inserting them? Can you provide the full stack strace of the exception?